# Route not getting resolved

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, redirecttoaction

I want clean URLs and have defined two routes:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Search",
    "Search",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "SearchPanel" }
);
routes.MapRoute(
    "SearchResults",
    "Search/{content}",
    new { controller = "Search", action = "Search", content = string.Empty, query = string.Empty, index = 0 }
);
```

then I have two actions:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Search(string content, string query)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Application");
    }
    return RedirectToAction("Search", new { content = content, query = query }); ;
}

public ActionResult Search(string content, string query, int? index)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(query))
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Home", "Application");
    }

    switch (content)
    {
        case "products":
            // get products
            return View("ResultsProducts");
        case "categories":
            // get categories
            return View("ResultsCategories");
        default:
            // get all
            return View("ResultsAll");
    }
}
```

I have a generic search panel in my master page that has a textbox and a submit button. It posts to `/Search`. Textbox's name is `query`. All fine and great. When I hit `Search` my first action gets executed, but fails on `RedirectToAction()` call:

**No route in the route table matches the supplied values.**

I can't seem to find the reason why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Removing `content`, `query` and `index` from defaults in second route, resolved the problem. Why is that I can't really tell, because those just define defaults, when they're not provided which in my case is not the case. I'm providing those values anyway.

Comment: I had a similar issue after updating to release 2 of MVC. I could navigate to the page specifying the URL, but if I tried to use RedirectToAction("ActionName") I got the same error: "No route in the route table...." In my case, I ended up duplicating the route entry the was working using the URL and removed the other parameters and now the RedirectToAction works also. Very strange....But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and thankfully this helped me so I want to give something back.

It seems there was a change in the MVC 2 framework which forces you to declare the routes in a different way.

In order to have the extra route values there (e.g. content) you must not assign the default of string.Empty, but rather have

```
content = UrlParameter.Optional
```

This should then allow your route evaluations to behave like it did in MVC 1.